ValueError: Expected EmbeddingFunction.__call__ to have the following signature: odict_keys(['self', 'input']), got odict_keys(['args', 'kwargs'])
1st Step:
I have been trying to use
2nd Step:
I have attached the output image
3rd step:
[vectorstore = Chroma.from_texts(to_vectorize, embeddings, metadatas=few_shots)]
Got a error
Overview:
I am working on an end-to-end LLM SQL project where users can ask questions and they will get the output
